# Help with a query in channel images

Tags: query, channel-images

I am using the following query to check if an entry in the channel images table has any categories marked 'private'.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_channel_images WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}'
 AND category = 'private' "}
 {if no_results} 0 images {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

The {if no_results} output does not work. Can anyone suggest another way I can do this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is a exp_channel_images is an actual table in your database? If you run that query on your database with 'open' do you get any results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems correct. Although, you can use channel images tag instead:

```
{exp:channel_images:images entry_id='entry_id' category='private'}
    {if image:no_images} 0 images {/if}
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```

In case you would like to use query module, it would work also:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total_images FROM exp_channel_images WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}' AND category = 'private'"}
 {if total_images == 0} 0 images {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhashkar I had previously tried the channel images tag but it doesn't work. The query module works and I have just simplified it further tojust do a basic count  `{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total_images FROM exp_channel_images WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}' AND category = 'private'"}
 {total_images} images
{/exp:query}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an EE database in front of me, but I could've sworn it was category_id in that table, not category. If your query is invalid, it would prevent no_results from working as well.